# analytic continuation of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Consider the holomorphic function $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$.  How do I find the largest open set to which $f$ can be analytically continued?  Is there a closed formula for $f$?

Comment: It can't be expressed elementarily. $-\int_0^z \frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\mathrm dt$ is what's termed as a *dilogarithm*...

Answer (score 2):

That function is called the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) $Li_2(z)$ or *dilogarithm*. It can be continued to the whole plane minus $0$ and $1$, which are then branch points; this is easy to see, using the integral representation that J.M. mentions in the comment above. The monodromy group is the Heisenberg group.

Comment: Wait, what? $0$ isn't a branch point... [right](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20PolyLog%5B2,x%5D%20for%20x%20from%20-1%20to%201)?

Comment: It is a branch point is some of the leaves (Morally, one of the branches of $\log(1-t)$ vanishes at zero, so there the pole of $1/t$ is killed; but on the other branches of $\log(1-t)$ the pole is quite there)

Comment: Oh, right. I was thinking of the principal value...

Comment: Mariano, Are you sure? The dilogarithm has an analytic continuation to the whole complex plane minus $(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Also, $\infty$ is a branch point I think.  So if you want a single-valued analytic continuation to a subset of the plane, that subset can be the complement of a curve starting at 1 and going to $\infty$.  The "principal branch" has this cut on the real interval $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: @Didier, Robert: If you continue the function starting from the obvious branch around $\tfrac12$ along a curve turning positively around $1$, and then all the way to $-1$ and which finally  makes several turns around 0, also in the positive direction, you find a logarithmic branching point there. This is discussed, for example, in http://links.jstor.org/sici?sici=1364-5021%2820031108%29459%3A2039%3C2807%3ATDFFCA%3E2.0.CO%3B2-F One does not see this on the obvious branch, which Robert mentions, but you do see it on the two branches to which you get when you cross Robert's cut.

Comment: Google turns out http://arxiv.org/abs/math.CA/0702243 which has a nice section doing the computation of the monodromy.

Comment: [Here](http://mathlab.snu.ac.kr/~top/articles/Dilogarithm%201.pdf) is a freely accessible version of the first article Mariano linked to.

Comment: Mariano, not sure I get your point. Are you saying that one can define a single-valued analytic function (which is what the OP asks for) on the complex plane minus $0$ and $1$? By the way, I think the correct answer to the OP is that there is no largest open set on which $f$ can be extended to a single-valued analytic function.

Comment: @Didier: I am saying that the if $\Sigma$ is the Riemann surface of the complete analytic function dilog and $p:\Sigma\to U$ is the map sending each germ in $\Sigma$ to its point (so that $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb C$, then $p$ is a branched covering space with $0$ and $1$ as branching points. I am using the vocabulary of Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable*, Chapter IX.

Comment: Mariano: Right. Hence $\mathbb C\setminus\{0,1\}$ is NOT an open set on which $f$ can be extended to a single-valued analytic function.

Comment: @Didier: I never said that.

Comment: The trouble is that you wrote that *The function* (...) *can be continued to the whole plane minus $0$ and $1$*... To prevent misunderstandings, I mention being well aware of the rest of your post and knowing what it means. BUT the same might not apply to every reader here.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I would have thought the largest open set was $\mathbb{C}-1$ since $0$ is a removable singularity of the integrand. I don't see how branch cuts enter the convo. Is that due to the log?